# Trying to return array of objects to view, get "10 $digest() iterations reached"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a tokenizer where the user inputs a formatted string and the UI gives them a preview of the parsed output. When I return the parsed tokens back to the UI, AngularJS gives the error "10 $digest() iterations reached." Here is a fiddle with a simplified example

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3phF/5/)

The important code is this:

JS:

```
$scope.getTokens = function() {
    return $scope.inputString.split(',').map(function(token) {
        return {
            cssClass: parseInt(token) % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd',
            content: token
        };
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input ng-model="inputString" />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='token in getTokens() track by $index' class='{{token.cssClass}}'>{{token.content}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I return a primitive value instead of an object, it works fine, but I want to send back more information. Strangely, the fiddle has the correct output but fills up the console.log with errors. I've read that this is usually caused by changing the collection while the render is happening, but I can't see where I've done that.

**How do I adjust my code to keep AngularJS from complaining about too many iterations?**

Answer (score 0):

I won't call a function inside `ngRepeat`, since the expression might be evaluated multiple times. Try this:

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="inputString" ng-change="getTokens()" />
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='token in tokens track by $index' class='{{token.cssClass}}'>{{token.content}}</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.inputString = '1,2,3,4';
    $scope.getTokens = function() {
        $scope.tokens = $scope.inputString.split(',').map(function(token) {
            return {
                cssClass: parseInt(token) % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd',
                content: token
            };
        });
    };
    $scope.getTokens();
});
```